# Can't edit site page without loosing all content

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, pages, view-styles

I have a major issue with my landing page.   Everytime I try to edit the page, I loose all the content, everything gets wiped out once I hit save and I've had to redo this page about 6 times now.  I can only go as far as adding two webparts, edit their options and four images, if I try to do more I loose it all.  This is not good becuase at this point all I can have in my landing page is an announcements list and a discussion board, nothing more.

I wonder if sharepoint pages have limitations as to the number of webparts that have been set with style "preview pane" , ever since i set both my announcements and discussion board list to this style, I've been having this issue.

Comment: If you add them using a different style does that stop the problem?

Comment: That's strange, maybe Dave gave us a clue, have you tried adding couple of web parts and content to a standard OOTB master page like v4 and see if you loose your content?

Comment: did you solve this? I have the same issue..